# Image editor in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, image

I am looking for a .net control that allows for the editing of images. The following features would be desirable:

- Crop
- Zoom
- Pen
- Line
- Brush
- Circle
- Polygon
- Full undo / redo
- Measure Tool
- Layers(not critical)

This control can either be  WPF, but would need to be extensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got answer refer this

http://web.archive.org/web/20150302041833/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools

This article describes the program that allows one to draw graphic objects on a WPF window using the mouse and certain drawing tools. The program supports the following tools: rectangle, ellipse, line, pencil and text. My first DrawTools article shows how to do this using Windows Forms. In the WPF version, I implemented a number of additional features requested by previous article readers:

Text tool
XML serialization
Drawing overlays on a background image
Printing
Zoom

Most of the requirement is completed by this reference.

Comment: the original source code and binaries for the Windows Forms (not the later WPF version) can be found in 2 projects that extend the original [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17893/Extensions-to-DrawTools) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/711081/DrawTools)